# Travel to Ercan enroute Larnaca

Tags: transit-visas, airport-transfer, nigerian-citizens, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I'm Nigeria passport holder and I intend to travel to northern Cyprus from Lagos but the best I got from Egypt Air is to Larnaca, Cyprus. Pls do I need a transit visa for Cyprus and also can I travel by land from Larnaca to Nicosia or get a local flight from Larnaca?

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of your trip to north Cyprus, and what documents do you have?

Comment: When are you planning to travel? Do you have a visa to enter Northern Cyprus? https://mfa.gov.ct.tr/consular-info/visa-regulations/

Comment: For the purpose of studying and am planning for December.

Comment: A transit visa will not work, because the Republic of Cyprus (where Larnaca is) does not recognize the Northern Cyprus government, which it views as an illegal Turkish creation. I think you would need a regular visa of some sort for Cyprus, and you can then cross into Northern Cyprus through certain checkpoints. Expect unpleasant questions. You would do much better to fly to Northern Cyprus via Turkey.